# An "exchanging $\sup$ and $\limsup$" question

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, maxima-minima

Let $a_{n,k}\in \mathbb{R}$ with:

- $0\leq  a_{n,k}\leq M$
- $\displaystyle a_{n,k} \rightarrow_k a_n$, uniformly with $n$

**Prove**: $$\displaystyle \sup_n\lim_ka_{n,k}\geq\limsup_k\sup_na_{n,k}$$

Does anybody know of a result that would help me out?

If I knew $\displaystyle a_{n,k} \rightarrow_n a_k$ I could conclude the existence of the double limits, and their equality, however here I cannot suppose this.

Comment: I think you don't have a "fundamental result" here to quote -- you need to try and find your own proof, using ideas of the proofs of results you already know.

Comment: Do you think the statement is true though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $\epsilon \gt 0$. By hypothesis on the uniform convergence of $\{a_{n,k}\}$ it exists $K \in \mathbb N$ such that for $k \ge K$ and $n \in \mathbb N$

$$ a_n - \epsilon \lt a_{n,k} \lt a_n + \epsilon.$$

As $0\leq  a_{n,k}\leq M$ for all $n,k \in \mathbb N$ $\sup_n a_n$ exists and for $k \ge K$ we have

$$\sup_n a_{n,k} \le \sup_n a_n + \epsilon$$ which means that

$$\sup_n a_{n,k} \le \sup_n \lim_k a_{n,k} + \epsilon$$ as $a_n$ is defined by $a_n = \lim_k a_{n,k}$. As the sequence in $k$ $\{\sup_n a_{n,k}\}$ is less than the real number $\sup_n \lim_k a_{n,k} + \epsilon$ for $k \ge K$ we obtain

$$\limsup_k\sup_n a_{n,k} \le \sup_n \lim_k a_{n,k} + \epsilon.$$ As this is true for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ we finally get the desired result

$$\limsup_k\sup_n a_{n,k} \le \sup_n \lim_k a_{n,k}.$$

Comment: Thank you, precise and very easy to follow.